# How do I customize the behavior of the base Google Map's place markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been working with the Google Maps API, and while I can add and customize my own markers and info windows, the base map has these default markers that display these info windows when clicked (picture below).

Is there any way to remove this behavior or implement my own (to make them more consistent with the behavior of markers my application adds) when clicking on these locations?

For example, it'd be nice to do be able to add my own marker upon clicking these markers. Something like:

```
defaultMarker.addListener("click", function () {
    myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ ... });
});
```

Except... I don't know of a way to grab these default markers.

Apologies if this has been answered before, or if I've just missed something basic entirely, but I couldn't find any documentation about these "default markers", for lack of better terminology.

[image: Google Maps Default Marker and InfoWindow]

Answer (score 5):

The current release version 3.24 of Maps JavaScript API has a property clickableIcons in the Map Options object:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

You can use this property to turn off clickable icons on maps by setting the clickableIcons property to false. Also exists a setClickableIcons() method.

Please look at this example: http://jsbin.com/liyamecoqa/edit?html,output

Answer (score 5):

In the newest release 3.26 You can do even more with place marker clicks.

You should listen to the "click" event of the Map object. If the user clicks on a POI, a IconMouseEvent is raised. This class extends the Regular MouseEvent and contains a property called placeId.

In the click event handler you can check if the event object has defined placeId. If it has then you have the place Id of clicked place. You should call the stop() method on the event to prevent maps from displaying the standard Info Window. You can use with Places API to get more info on the icon that was clicked, and open an info window that looks and behaves as your own info windows.

I prepared a small demo which shows how you can do this:

http://jsbin.com/parapex/10/edit?html,output

The ClickEventHandler object takes care of routing to the clicked place and gets details from the Places Service and displays them in a custom info window.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the stop() method! Been looking for a way to disable the default infowindow for hours.